# Can our website automatically apply background music to a recording made via the site?

Tags: podcasts, backgroundambience

We have a website that will allow users to create a voice recording from a Record button on the site.  After they record, we'd like to allow them to pick from a prerecorded list of background music which (after they create the post) would play as background music to their voice recording.

Can this be done?  Is it simply playing two files at the same time and us programming the background music to play at a lower volume?  I am obviously not a sound guy, so keep it simple please.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Another option : use of the [Web Audio API](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/) on the client side.

That's basically two audio sources and one [mixer](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#mixer-gain-structure).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can do this. Various techniques would work, but in simplest terms:

Create a single file from two audio files and serve this, either as a file or streaming.

It really is that easy.